# Compare Pandas DatetimeIndex to a smaller DatetimeIndex with condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I am trying to compare two Pandas DatetineIndexs with different lengths.  I want to simply add a new column to my larger Dataframe (df) and place 1 where it matches the smaller DatetineIndex (events).

I tried

```
df['filter'] = np.where(df.index == tEvents, 1, np.nan)
```

but I get "ValueError: Lengths must match to compare"

I've been stuck here longer than I like to admit

[image: Comparing different python datetime index with different lengths]

Comment: `tEvents` and `df.index` are different lengths. I believe you want `df.index in tEvents` not `df.index == tEvents`

Comment: @W Stokvis, thanks I believe this is what I am looking for. Can you post it as an answer so I can mark it as solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tEvents` and `df.index` are different lengths. `df.index == tEvents` looks to compare the two lists.

You want to check if an element in `df.index` is in `tEvents`. Thus replace `df.index == tEvents` with `df.index.isin(tEvents)`

To see add a True or false value if date matches, use [DataFrame.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

Comment: `df.index in tEvents` won't work, because indexes aren't hashable.  That's trying to check if the `df.index` object itself, not its constituent elements, is in tEvents.  You probably want `df.index.isin(tEvents)`.

Comment: @DSM adjusted the answer. Thanks for the feedback.