# Pandas dynamically pattern match from second dataframe and extract string

Tags: regex, pandas, substring, lookup

Getting my knickers in a twist trying to dynamically build a regex extract pattern from a second dataframe list and populate another column with the string if it's contained in the list.

here are the two starting tables:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

# this is a short extract, there are 1000's of records in this table:
provinces = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['Brazil','Brazil','Brazil','Colombia','Colombia','Colombia'],
                  'area': ['Cerrado','Sul de Minas', 'Mococoa','Tolima','Huila','Quindio'],
                  'index': [13,21,19,35,36,34]})

# test dataframe
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'country':['brazil','brazil','brazil','brazil','colombia','colombia','brazil'],
                       'locality':['sul de minas minas gerais','chapadao cerrado','cerrado cerrado','mococa sao paulo','pitalito huila','pijao quindio','espirito santo']})
```

```
print(provinces)

    country          area  index
0    Brazil       Cerrado     13
1    Brazil  Sul de Minas     21
2    Brazil       Mococoa     19
3  Colombia        Tolima     35
4  Colombia         Huila     36
5  Colombia       Quindio     34

print(df_test)
    country                   locality
0    brazil  sul de minas minas gerais
1    brazil           chapadao cerrado
2    brazil            cerrado cerrado
3    brazil           mococa sao paulo
4  colombia             pitalito huila
5  colombia              pijao quindio
6    brazil             espirito santo
```

and end result:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'country':['brazil','brazil','brazil','brazil','colombia','colombia','brazil'],
                       'locality':['minas gerais','chapadao','cerrado','sao paulo','pitalito','pijao','espirito santo'],
                         'area': ['sul de minas','cerrado','cerrado','mococoa','huila','quindio',''],
                         'index': [21,13,13,19,36,34,np.nan]})
print(df_result)
    country        locality          area  index
0    brazil    minas gerais  sul de minas   21.0
1    brazil        chapadao       cerrado   13.0
2    brazil         cerrado       cerrado   13.0
3    brazil       sao paulo       mococoa   19.0
4  colombia        pitalito         huila   36.0
5  colombia           pijao       quindio   34.0
6    brazil  espirito santo                  NaN
```

Can't get around the first step to populate the area column. Once the area column contains a string, stripping the same string from the locality column and adding the index column with a left join on the country and area columns is the easy part(!)

```
# to create the area column and extract the area string if there's a match (by string and country) in the provinces table
df_test['area'] = ''
df_test.area = df_test.locality.str.extract(flags=re.IGNORECASE, pat = r'(\b{}\b)'.format('|'.join(provinces.loc[provinces.country.str.lower()==df_test.country,'area'].str.lower().to_list()), expand=False))
```

and I'd also need to apply a map to exclude some records from this step.

```
# as above but for added complexity, populate the area column only if df_test.country == 'brazil':
df_test['area'] = ''
mapping = df_test.country =='brazil'
df_test.loc[mapping,'area'] = df_test.loc[mapping,'locality'].str.extract(flags=re.IGNORECASE, pat = r'(\b{}\b)'.format('|'.join(provinces.loc[provinces.country.str.lower()==df_test.country,'area'].str.lower().to_list()), expand=False))
```

All the vectorised regex extract solutions I've found rely on [pre-defined regex patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22703494/find-string-pattern-match-in-pandas-dataframe-and-return-matched-strin), but given these patterns need to come from the provinces dataframe where the countries match, this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52265419/join-dataframes-based-on-partial-string-match-between-columns) seemed like the closet match to this scenario but I couldn't make sense of it...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

following the trail of error messages (and sleep!), "Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects"  resolved with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067449/valueerror-can-only-compare-identically-labeled-series-objects-python)

And then "ValueError: Lengths must match to compare" with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447695/compare-pandas-datetimeindex-to-a-smaller-datetimeindex-with-condition)

here's the solution:

```
df_test['area'] = ''
df_test.area = df_test.locality.str.extract(flags=re.IGNORECASE, pat = r'({})'.format('|'.join(provinces.loc[provinces.country.str.lower().isin(df_test.country),'area'].str.lower().to_list()), expand=False))
```

```
[out]

   country                   locality          area
0    brazil  sul de minas minas gerais  sul de minas
1    brazil           chapadao cerrado       cerrado
2    brazil            cerrado cerrado       cerrado
3    brazil          mococoa sao paulo       mococoa
4  colombia             pitalito huila         huila
5  colombia              pijao quindio       quindio
6    brazil             espirito santo           NaN
```